# How to update UI in button click before and after task runs

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms, task

I have a Web Forms app where I need to show a progress spinner when button is clicked, and hide it when a task finishes executing. I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this. I can only get either the hide or show functionality to work properly but not both. For the code below, the spinner isn't shown until after the page reloads (I tested this by removing the hide spinner part). So basically, the hiding part occurs and works as expected but the show part does not.

As a side note, the page is in a re-load state for the duration of this method. Thanks for any help!

```
    protected async void btnPullQBData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadingContainer.Visible = true;
        string type = "";
        string response = "";

        response = await SyncData();
        loadingContainer.Visible = false;
    }

    public Task<string> SyncData()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            QBService service = new QBService(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            string response = service.RefreshDBFromQB();
            return response;
        });
    }
```

Comment: What you're thinking of doing is *not* how Web Forms works and there is no UI thread. Background operations in Web Forms must be done very differently (specifically, usually via AJAX) or a RESTful model where a resource represents an ongoing background operation.

Comment: use javascript to set visibility to true onClientClick and then set it to false in the serverside method